Programmatically set layout and ticks padding
I have a use-case where I draw icons above chart.js' ticks. Those icons are responsive so I resize them using options.onResize. I am aware of options.layout.padding.top and options.scales.x.ticks.padding, but those are set on initialization and changing them in onResize using chart.options.layout.padding.top and chart.options.scales.x.ticks.padding doesn't modify that initial padding.
Is there an documented API I can use to change those layout and ticks padding?

you can edit the data and then call the chart.update() function so it updates the data

Yep, that works, thanks. Can you post it as an answer?

i made a short answer because it doesnt need alot of explenation

When chart is initialized it creates an instance of an chart in an canvas.
if it it gets new data the chart does get the new data but doesnt update the canvas beacause it doesnt get the command to update the view.
the command itself is chart.update() code link chart.js.
